# how to change image URL for each image of 4 products on each row?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I have a dynamic product table with 4 product on each row. I'm using CSS and not an html table.
I'm looking for a way to change all 4 images on each row to different urls and to do the same on all the other rows.

The reason for this is to use 4 sub domains as CDN to allow faster downloads.

Is this possible? i'm still very junior so need some assistance.

Below is my code and the image section is     `<img class="lazy" src="/images/loading.gif" data-original="<?=resize($i['image'],$settings)?>" width="170" height="250" alt="" />`
You will notice that i'm using data-original as i'm using lazyload, the $settings is used for creating a cached version of the image.

Here's my code...

```
if($viewing=='retailer'){
if($i['category']!=$categoryCheck){?>
<div id="sub-sub"><?=$i['category_name']?></div>
<?
$categoryCheck = $i['category']; $y=1;
}?><? } ?>


        <div class="package"<?=$y==4?' style="margin-right:0;"':''?><?=$y==1?' style="clear:left;"':''?>>
            <div class="package-img"><a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="<?=$buyLink?>">


            <?php $settings = array('w'=>170,'h'=>250,'canvas-color'=>'#ffffff'); ?>
<img class="lazy" src="/images/loading.gif" data-original="<?=resize($i['image'],$settings)?>" width="170" height="250" alt="" />

<noscript><img src="<?=resize($i['image'],$settings)?>" width="640" heigh="480"></noscript>
<? /* <img src="<?=$i['image']?>" width="640" heigh="480"> */ ?>
            </a></div>

            <div class="name"><a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="<?=$buyLink?>"><?=$i['item_name']?></a></div>
                    <div class="price"><p>&pound;<?=$i['price']?></div>         
            <a href="<?=$buyLink?>"><div class="mrtl rtl<?=$i['retailer']?>"></div></a>

            <div class="retailer-image"><a href="<?=$buyLink?>"><img src="/images/retailers/<?=$i['retailer_logo']?>" width="140" heigh="46" /></a></div>


                    </div>
        <?
        $y = $y==4 ? 1 : $y+1;
    }
```

Comment: So on each row i would like there to be 4 images all with different url... cdn.domain. com,cdn2.domain. com, cdn3.domain. com, cdn4.domain. com,

Comment: can you add the url to the src of each image?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your function which returns the path to the image.

```
<?php

function resize(..., ...) {

    static $i = 0;

    $i++;

    if ($i == 5) {
        $i = 1;
    }

    return "http://cdn{$i}.domain/images/blah.gif";

}

?>
```

Comment: using `rand()` will defeat any performance gains on subsequent page loads because it will be very hit and miss regarding browser having cached images

Comment: true, I probably shouldn't have added any code here, all he needs to do is prepend the image path. Even with the changed code above, it's still dependent on the images being shown in the same order.

Comment: The solution was `
$cdn_image = 'http://cdn'.($k%4 + 1).'.domain.com';?>
<img class="lazy" src="/images/loading.gif" data-original="<?=$cdn_image;?><?=resize($i['image'],$settings)?>" width="170" height="250" alt="" />`